# I need to get the URL from the element "name" in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have tried

```
 private string GetId(int index)
        {
            var xPath = "xpath";
            var name = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(xPath)).GetAttribute("href");

            return name[0].Text;
        }
```

Error

... does not contain a definition for 'GetAttribute' and no accessible extension method 'GetAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'ReadOnlyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?...

Comment: `FindElements` return's a `ReadOnlyCollection<WebElement>` and you're trying to call `GetAttribute` on that collection, hence the reason for the error you're getting. Do you want all `href` attributes? Could you update your post to include more detail, examples and expected output?

Answer (score -1):

"driver.FindElements()" returns an array of found elements, so if you want to read the "href" attribute of the first found element, you should use this code:

```
var name = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(xPath));

return name[0].GetAttribute("href");
```